# Aggregate two row in R, by their sum

Tags: r, matrix, aggregate

Say I have a matrix like this:

```
    x y z f
  a 2 2 3 10
  b 2 3 1 90
  c 2 2 3 10
```

What I wanted is when x, y and z is equal in two row I want to merge them by their sum on f. Here a and c is identical by x, y and z, and I want to add c's f to a's f.

So what I get will be this:

```
    x y z f
  a 2 2 3 20
  b 2 3 1 90
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: `aggregate(f ~. , m, sum)` if `m` is your matrix

Comment: @David Arenburg, Is this identical to what you said?

`aggregate(dat, by=list(dat[,1],dat[,2],dat[,3]), FUN=sum)`

Comment: @herbivor It creates additional columns in the output

Comment: It is identical to `aggregate(f ~ x + y + z, m, sum)`. It also better to use the formula notation for better readability.

Comment: @DavidArenburg how can I make this more readable like in the link you marked as the answer?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @DavidArenburg As I see you marked this question as a duplicate and referenced this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group 
So how can I make it more readable, like in the link. I don't know the formula notation yet.

Comment: I don't understand, I showed you `aggregate(f ~ x + y + z, m, sum)`, isn't this readable?

Comment: It's readable, but in the link you marked as answer(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group) it's not formula notation I guess, and that seems more readable to me as I am new to R. Whatever, I'll use the notation one, thanks.

Comment: Then, something like `aggregate(m[, 4], by=list(m[,1],m[,2],m[,3]), sum)` probably

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the 'formula' method from `aggregate`.  Here `.` denotes all the other variables in the dataset.

```
aggregate(f~., m1, FUN=sum)
```

It can be explicitly written as

```
aggregate(f~x+y+z, m1, FUN=sum)
```

It would be useful if are using only a subset of variables as the grouping variable.

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 90L, 10L
), .Dim = 3:4, .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("x", "y", 
"z", "f")))
```

Comment: Don't think you need to convert to a `data.frame` and this is just a dupe Id guess

Comment: @DavidArenburg You are right.  I didn't check that.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I didn't know that the formula method will work with matrix without explicitly converting to 'data.frame' as `‘aggregate.formula’ is a standard formula interface to
     ‘aggregate.data.frame’` in the documentation